# Bootstrap Layout Suggestions for 50 50 layout with Image and Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Looking for suggestions to create a 50 50 split layout with bootstrap. One side image, and the other side text. The text side should always stay the equal size/height of the image. The text side should stay centered vertically.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

[Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR9YP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I made a CodePen you can look at here
https://codepen.io/andrea-garza/pen/jOBXdjY

Below is the HTML. If you prefer to use a fixed width container just replace "container-fluid" with "container". The div class "mycontent" I gave some padding left and right of the text when viewed on desktop and tablets, but the padding is removed on phones. The class class="photo" is the background image. The CSS has the url to the image, change this to your image source. The background is set to cover the area and have a min height which changes as the browser collapses, simply edit min-height in the CSS for whatever you need it to be.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flex-row">
<div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center mycontent">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero nisi, posuere ac placerat convallis, imperdiet at libero. Sed vitae nibh molestie nisl bibendum finibus mollis tincidunt dui. Morbi quis purus non lectus rutrum finibus ut a mi. Nullam feugiat tortor nec ultrices aliquam. Fusce sed auctor ex. Sed sapien risus, commodo rutrum augue mattis, rutrum dapibus ex. Suspendisse at posuere magna. Fusce a magna vitae enim dignissim pellentesque. Mauris cursus et elit ac congue. Fusce luctus eget ante a interdum. Nunc malesuada imperdiet lectus eu placerat. Pellentesque aliquet neque orci, non malesuada mi convallis at.</p> 
</div><!-- end col -->
  
<div class="col-md-6 photo">
 <!-- nothing goes here its just a photo but you could if you wanted to -->  
</div><!-- end col -->
  
</div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Below is the corresponding CSS

```
.mycontent {
  padding:0 4%;
}

.photo {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/4894421/pexels-photo-4894421.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  min-height:500px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .photo {min-height:350px;}
  .mycontent {padding:0 4%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .photo {min-height:325px;}
  .mycontent {padding:0;}
}
```

Comment: This is working very well, thanks! I tried upvoting but don't have enough points yet. 
Is there a bootstrap class that will make sure the image is always centered vertically if the text on the left side grows bigger than the image itself?

Comment: @TanookiMario  The statement in the CSS   background-position: 50% 50%; aligns the image to the center both horizontally and vertically in the photo column.

Comment: What do I need to modify or add so that the two columns stack instead of the image side swapping sides & the resizing instead of stacking?